# Reading data from csv file using pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm trying to read a csv file on pig shell on mac. All I'm doing is `load` a file into a variable and `dump` the variable. Here is how I'm doing it:

```
movies = LOAD '/user/myhome/movies_data.csv' USING PigStorage(',') as (id,name,year,rating,duration);
DUMP movies;
```

The data I'm using is downloaded from github provided [here](http://www.rohitmenon.com/index.php/apache-pig-tutorial-part-1/)

This file is available in locally installed hdfs on my mac. When I do `dump` I get an error:

> org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias movies
>
> at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:935)  at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:754)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:376)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:230)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:205)
>     at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:66)  at
>   org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:565)    at
>   org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:177)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136) Caused by:
>   java.io.IOException: Job terminated with anomalous status FAILED  at
>   org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:927)     ... 13 more

When I hit the app cluster link when this job is run, I get the following exception:

> Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
>   Container id: container_1443887668938_0007_02_000001 Exit code: 127
>   Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=127: at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:538) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:211)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Container exited with a
>   non-zero exit code 127 Failing this attempt. Failing the application.

Pig version is 0.15.0 and hadoop is 2.6.1. Am I missing something here?

Comment: a related post, check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20350122/error-1066-unable-to-open-iterator-for-alias-pig

Comment: Was not helpful though. As far as versions are concerned, I'm using pig 0.15.0 and hadoop is 2.6.1

Comment: @coder : I don't see any issue with the script. Can you check if the file is available in hdfs if your are running pig in cluster mode ? Can you try having this file in your local drive and running the same example in local mode (pig -x local) ?

Comment: For people who found this post when looking for [ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495085/error-1066-unable-to-open-iterator-for-alias-in-pig-generic-solution) here is a [generic solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34495086/983722).

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSVLoader from piggybank. Get the piggybank jar if not available and register it and use the CSVLoader. Something like this.

```
register '/your/path/to/piggybank/jar' ;
define CSVLoader org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVLoader();
movies = LOAD '/user/myhome/movies_data.csv' USING CSVLoader as (id,name,year,rating,duration);
```

Comment: But shouldn't using PigStorage() work out of the box here? I do not understand what I'm missing here.

Comment: It should i just tried with your dataset. The dataset also looks good. But with your error it seems pig is not able to parse the data.

Comment: Yes I'm unable to understand why.